# Tracing 2d coordinates by using Nearest function

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, nearest

In 5 digital images I have determined the 2d coordinates of detected objects. 
The resulting coordinate list can be downloaded from here: http://pastebin.com/7bE0CEJ5

```
list= {{{1, {533.286, 574.643}}, ... , {443, {371., 3.5}}}}
```

whereby

`Dimensions /@ list` gives

```
{{443, 2}, {443, 2}, {444, 2}, {442, 2}, {443, 2}}
```

A color coded plot of the coordinates in all 5 images is shown here:

[image]

```
colors = {Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red}
```

The colors correspond to the image sequence.

Since only red points are seen, it shows that the displacement of the objects is very small.

A selection where only one particle trace is seen is:

[image]

This shows how an object randomly vibrates.

The *number of detected objects per image is varying (443 -> 443 -> 444 -> 442 -> 443)*, because new objects can appear in an image (not detected in the image before) or/and objects detected in an image can disappear in the next one.

Now I want to trace the (same) objects (their coordinates) in the 5 images by using the `Nearest` function.
The objects are moving only slightly from image to image (much less than than half of their mean distance), therefore `Nearest` is appropriate.

The coordinates of the objects in the 5 images are:

```
coordinates1 = list[[1]][[All, 2]];
coordinates2 = list[[2]][[All, 2]]
coordinates3 = list[[3]][[All, 2]]
coordinates4 = list[[4]][[All, 2]]
coordinates5 = list[[5]][[All, 2]]
```

To find the `Nearest` neighbors to object 1 in `coordinates1` I can write:

```
c1 = coordinates1[[1]];
c2 = Nearest[coordinates2, c1][[1]];
c3 = Nearest[coordinates3, c2][[1]];
c4 = Nearest[coordinates4, c3][[1]];
c5 = Nearest[coordinates5, c4][[1]];
```

Combined in a trace-list for object 1 this yields:

`{c1,c2,c3,c4,c5}` =

`{{533.286, 574.643}, {533.667, 574.667}, {533.115, 574.654}, {533.167, 574.633}, {533.115, 574.654}}`

For object 440 this gives:

```
c1 = coordinates1[440]];
c2 = Nearest[coordinates2, c1][[1]];
c3 = Nearest[coordinates3, c2][[1]];
c4 = Nearest[coordinates4, c3][[1]];
c5 = Nearest[coordinates5, c4][[1]];
```

Combined in a trace-list for object 440 this yields:

`{c1,c2,c3,c4,c5}` =

`{{190.5, 3.5}, {192., 3.5}, {191.5, 3.5}, {187.975, 17.775}, {188.23, 18.1216}}`

**To improve this elements-wise calculation, `Nearest` can also be called with two lists:**

```
Nearest[coordinates2 , coordinates1]
```

This gives the nearest neighbors in `coordinates2` relativ to `coordinates1`:

```
{{{533.667, 574.667}}... , {{373., 3.5}}}
```

This gives the following code:

```
n1 = coordinates1;
n2 = Nearest[coordinates2, coordinates1];
n3 = Nearest[coordinates3, coordinates2];
n4 = Nearest[coordinates4, coordinates3];
n5 = Nearest[coordinates5, coordinates4];
```

From that I can get **accidentally** all traces for object 1 (as shown above):

`{{n1[[1]], n2[[1]], n3[[1]], n4[[1]], n5[[1]]}` =

`{{533.286, 574.643}, {{533.667, 574.667}}, {{533.115, 574.654}}, {{533.167, 574.633}}, {{533.115, 574.654}}}`

But it is wrong e.g for number 440 (see correct trace results above):

`{n1[[440]], n2[[440]], n3[[440]], n4[[440]], n5[[440]]}` =

`{{190.5, 3.5}, {{192., 3.5}}, {{11.75, 3.25}}, {{487.958, 6.33333}}, {{489.154, 6.19231}}}`

How can I obtain the correct traces for all coordinates in the 5 images?

To call `Nearest` with two lists is probably fastest. But the problem here is that I have to find out how to assign the correct indices of `n1` to `n5`to represent the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `l` is your list:

```
l1 = l[[All, All, 2]];
g = Nearest[l1[[#]] -> Automatic] & /@ Range@Length@l1; 
corr[i_] := MapIndexed[{g[[i]][#1, {1, 7}], #2} &, l1[[i + 1]]]
ls = Fold[#1 /. {s___, {x_}} :> {s, {x}, Cases[#2, {{x}, _}][[1, 2]]} &, corr /@ Range@4]
```

I'm using V9 syntax above, it can probably be shorter if you use V10's

Let's Animate the displacements:

```
ls1 = Cases[Flatten /@ ls, {_Integer, Integer_, Integer_, Integer_, Integer_}];
ls2 = ls1 /. {a_Integer, b_Integer, c_Integer, d_Integer, e_Integer} :>  
             Quiet@Evaluate[l1[[##]] & @@@ Thread[{Range@5, {a, b, c, d, e}}]];
ls3 = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ ls2;
ls4 = ls3 /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {{a, b}, {c, d} - {a, b}};
ListAnimate[ ListVectorPlot[#, PlotRange -> {{-100, 900}, {0, 700}}] & /@ Transpose@ls4]
```

[image]

Comment: The `7` is empirical

Comment: incredibly ... I have to check this tomorrow

Comment: This problem for wrong coordinate assignment could be solved by considering that only nearest coordinates should be tracked that are below a certain radius. How could that be integrated? The coordinates that belong to a trace are much less than (half of) the mean object spacing.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = Map[Last, list, {2}];

res = 
   Rest@FoldList[First@Nearest[c[[#2]], #1] &, c[[1, #]], Range@Length@c] & /@ 
      Range@Length@First@c; // AbsoluteTiming // First

0.160000
```

And now simply

```
res[[1]]
```

> {{533.286, 574.643}, {533.667, 574.667}, {533.115, 574.654}, {533.167,
>      574.633}, {533.115, 574.654}}

or

```
res[[440]]
```

> {{190.5, 3.5}, {192., 3.5}, {191.5, 3.5}, {187.975, 17.775}, {188.23, 
>     18.1216}}

Comment: Not sure ... `res[[414]]` and `res[[439]]` (for example) both end with the same "particle"

Comment: I'm not sure either. I just thought that `FoldList` (instead of all those variable names) might facilitate the calculations of the OP . Also, my results for `1 and `440` are equal to his results.

Comment: This problem could be solved by considering that only nearest coordinates should be tracked that are below a certain radius. How could that be integrated? The coordinates that belong to a trace are much less than (half of) the mean object spacing.